# Javascript function which returns the date of the next specific weekday

Tags: javascript, date

I am writing a function in JavaScript which takes in a weekday string and a date object and returns the date of the next weekday.

I am pretty inexperienced with working with dates, and what I have written seems a bit complex - and am thinking there is probably a far simpler way to write the code.

Would anyone mind having a look and seeing if they could provide some feedback on how it could be improved?

`getLessonDate()` would be called with the weekday string and date object, and use the helper functions to derive the days til the next weekday, and ultimately provide the next weekday date object.

Thanks so much in advance

```js
// returns remaining days left in the week (ending
// Saturday). Does not include the day that is
// passed in (dayInt)
const remaingDaysInTheWeek = (dayInt) => 6 - dayInt;

// returns the numbers of days until tarket weekday (including
// weekday passed to fn)
const dayOfTheWeekCount = (weekday) => dow.indexOf(weekday) + 1;

// fn to calculate how many days until next weekday
const calculateDaysUntilNextWeekWeekday = (todayInt, lessonWeekdayString) =>
  remaingDaysInTheWeek(todayInt) + dayOfTheWeekCount(lessonWeekdayString);

const getLessonDate = (lessonWeekdayString, todayDateObj) => {
  const todayWeekdayInt = todayDateObj.getDay();
  const lessonDayInt = dow.indexOf(lessonWeekdayString);
  let lessonDate = todayDateObj;

  const daysToAdd =
    todayWeekdayInt <= lessonDayInt
      ? lessonDayInt - todayWeekdayInt
      : calculateDaysUntilNextWeekWeekday(todayWeekdayInt, lessonWeekdayString);

  lessonDate.setDate(todayDateObj.getDate() + daysToAdd);

  return lessonDate;
};
```

Comment: I must be not understanding  something that others do... the goal is next weekday (not saturday or sunday) after a given date `todayDateOj`.  This can be computed from just the date, without regard to `lessonWeekdayString`.  Why do we need lessonWeekdayString?

Comment: do you have to use that custom function or you can use a library for handling date? there is a date fns library that offers everything you need.

Comment: Note: you’re mutating todayDateObj here which is almost certainly unintentional and could be a source of bugs.

Comment: Thanks Adam, is this line the mutation? Can you explain that a bit further? `let lessonDate = todayDateObj;`

Comment: @LeMoi that’s the start of it. lessonDate is now the same object as todayDateObj. The mutation happens when you call setDate on lessonDate, which is the same as todayDateObj, which means you’re mutating todayDateObj. The way to prevent mutation is to say lessonDate = new Date(todayDateObj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic goes like this:

1. Start with tomorrow (you're looking for the ***next*** weekday)
2. Loop until your `getDay` matches the correct day
3. Return that date

```
const dow = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

const nextDay = (dayString, date) => {
   const dayIndex = dow.indexOf(dayString)
   const nextDate = new Date(date)
   nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1) // start with tomorrow
   while(nextDate.getDay() !== dayIndex) {
     nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1)
   }
   return nextDate
}
```

You could do it with math operations, too, as you did. But I personally find the loop easier to grok - there’s very little logic in the loop function to read

Weekdays don’t really have anything to do with this either, you want a function that returns the next date given a certain day string, it’s not particularly relevant that the day string will always be a weekday when the function is used. I have a suspicion that a requirement of the next “weekday” made the code more complicated than necessary.

EDIT: Here's the math if you don't like the loop

The days to the end of the week is 7 minus the current day index. Then you add the day index for the desired day of the week. If the currentDayIndex is less than the desired day index, just add the difference, so it's a simple ternary:

```
const dow = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

const nextDay = (dayString, date) => {
   const dayIndex = dow.indexOf(dayString)
   const currentDayIndex = date.getDay();
   // currentDay >= dayIndex, add the dayIndex to the days until the end of the week, which is 7-currentDayIndex
   // otherwise, just set it to the difference of the dayIndex and the currentDayIndex
   const daysToAdd = currentDay >= dayIndex ? 7-currentDayIndex+dayIndex : dayIndex - currentDayIndex
   const nextDate = new Date(date)
   nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + daysToAdd)
   return nextDate
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm to get the next instance of a particular day of the week from a given date is:

1. Subtract the current day index from the required day index
2. If the value is less than 1, add seven

You can also replace the "if" with "or":

1. Subtract the current day index from the required day index
2. Add 7
3. Get the remainder after dividing by 7 (i.e. %7)
4. Return the result OR 7 (which is effectively if result == 0, return 7)

E.g.

```js
function getNextWeekdayByName(weekday, date = new Date()) {
  let days = ['su','mo','tu','we','th','fr','sa'];
  let idx = days.indexOf(weekday.toLowerCase().substr(0,2));
  let f = ((7 + idx - date.getDay()) % 7) || 7;
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + f);
}

console.log('Today: ' + new Date().toDateString());
// Next instance of each day of the week from today
['Monday','Tue','wed','thurzdy','Fryday','sat', 'Sunday']
  .forEach(day => console.log(
    day + ': ' + getNextWeekdayByName(day).toDateString()
  ));
```

Using just the first two letters of the day name as lower case just reduces the opportunity for spelling mistakes. Maybe that's desirable nor not.

Answer (score 1):

you could use moment.js

```js
const func = (lessonWeekdayString, todayDateObj)=>{
  // could be date obj or string ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'|'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  // or undefined to use the actual date
  const days={
    'monday':1,
    'tuesday':2,
    'wednesday':3,
    'thursday':4,
    'friday':5,
    'saturday':6,
    'sunday':7
  };
  return moment(todayDateObj).day(days[lessonWeekdayString]);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-ace-csl2m3